# Execute Linux command with PHP?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

I'm really confused on how to actually execute Linux commands with PHP.
Say I wan't to reboot the Server with the `reboot` command, how do I do it?
I tried to:

```
exec('reboot');
```

but it seems there's more to do.
Thanks in advance

PS I had no problem with output eg `echo exec('hostname -I')` but I want to be able to run programs etc

Comment: `reboot` requires root privileges, and you most certainly should not be running your webserver as root. If anything, use `sudo reboot`, and give the webserver user privileges to specific commands.

Comment: forgot to mention, this is for personal use(not www just localhost)

Comment: btw I can run `reboot` on Ubuntu without `sudo`(not logged in as the root user)

Comment: Nope, still not working. I tried to run it as root with `echo my_password | sudo -S reboot`(which works on terminal) and still nothing...

Comment: What is the output? What is the issue?

Comment: Try capturing stderr with `echo exec('reboot 2>&1')` to see if you're getting an error.

Comment: what user is your php app running as, and does that user have sufficient permissions to execute reboot?

Comment: Matt, I tried `exec('echo my_assword | sudo -S reboot', $out, $err);` the `$err` value is `1` but the `$out` count is 0(that's not normal, right?)

Comment: Barmar, I get a `Must be root.` echoed. and when I run it as root `echo exec("echo user | sudo -S reboot 2>&1");` I get `sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt`. <br>
Note : My user(literally the password is 'user') password is correct, I know this because I use it every half an hour ...

Comment: Lucha Laura, `echo exec('whoami');` returns `www-data`

Answer (score 0):

Put the following line in /etc/sudoers.d/web:

`www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot`

Assuming www-data is web server user. Now you should be able to reboot the server with php code. Any errors should come in the error log.

Replace /sbin/reboot with the full path of the command you want to run. If you have multiple commands to run replace it with a list of comma separated commands like /sbin/reboot, /bin/echo

Comment: That worked for the `reboot` command but it doesn't work on anything else I tested eg when I try to run chromium with `echo exec("echo 'user' | sudo -S chromium-browser 2>&1");` I get a `Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:` error

Comment: did you put lxtask to the /etc/sudoers.d/web file? and it seems you are trying to run GUI applications. Whats the purpose of running GUI apps via php?

Comment: Indeed I want to run GUI apps. I'm a web developer and I'm trying to make some customized site so that I use the PC while I'm sitting on my couch with a remote ... I have little experience with C# but that's it, everything else is web-dev languages so if i want to make any software it's going to be mostly with PHP. For example one command I would surely use is ` `chromium-browser --kiosk youtube.com/tv`

Comment: I actually entered `www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` for testing purposes ... maybe I will restrict this later(when I'm done with PHP)

Comment: Not sure if GUI apps can be launched this way. Normally only CLI apps are run using php using exec() or shell_exec()